# Alternative to a monitor to checking for the existence of a record, and writing it if it doesn't exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, concurrency, entity-framework-core

So I have a bit of C# code that looks like the below (simplified for the purpose of the question, any bugs are from me making these changes). This code can be called from multiple threads or contexts, in an asynchronous fashion.  The whole purpose of this is to make sure that if a record already exists, it is used, and if it doesn't it gets created.  May or may not be great design, but this works as expected.

```
var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
bool lockTaken = false;

try
{
    Monitor.TryEnter(m_lock, timeout, ref lockTaken);  // m_lock declared statically above
    if (lockTaken)
    {
        var myDBRecord = _DBContext.MyClass.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ForeignKeyId1 == ForeignKeyId1
                                                              && x.ForeignKeyId2 == ForeignKeyId2);
        
        if (myDBRecord == null)
        {
           myDBRecord = new MyClass
           {    
                ForeignKeyId1 == ForeignKeyId1,
                ForeignKeyId2 == ForeignKeyId2
                // ...datapoints
           };
           _DBContext.MyClass.Add(myDBRecord);
           _DBContext.SaveChanges();
       }
   }
   else
   {
       throw new Exception("Can't get lock");
   }
}
finally
{
   if (lockTaken)
   {
       Monitor.Exit(m_lock);
   }
}
```

The problem occurs if there are a lot of requests that come in, it can overwhelm the monitor, timing out if it has to wait too long.  While the timeout for the lock can certainly be shorter, what is the preferred approach, if any, to addressing this type of a problem?  Anything that would try to see if the monitor'd code needed to be entered would need to be part of that atomic operation.

Comment: WRT "lot of requests that come in" what numbers are we talking about?

Comment: @DaleK unfortunately I couldn't tell you other than to say multiple requests a second.  I could lower the timeout of the monitor but at some point with an increasing number of requests if they are coming in faster than they are going out some will drop on the floor.  Maybe that is unavoidable.

Comment: Well its a bit hard to advise if you're not actually sure - why not log it? Multiple requests per second is nothing... but maybe your code is slow? You need to have some idea of the demand you are trying to meet in order to come up with the best solution. And you also need to have some idea of how long it takes to process a request. Because to allocate a single record should be trivial.

Comment: In fact you could answer all your questions by running the SQL Server Profiler and logging for a minute or so.

Comment: shouldnt this logic live in the database layer?

Comment: This kind of logic in a website seems odd, since the lock won't work during a deployment or if there is a web farm / garden.

Comment: There is no explanation here as to why an exception is being thrown if the lock tryenter fails. Either this code is redundant or there are more requirements than meet the eye

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you get rid of the monitor altogether and instead handle the duplicate key exception. You have to handle the condition where you are trying to enter a duplicate value anyway, why not do so directly?